# Execvp Only runs the first command correctly

Tags: c++, c, linux, shell, execvp

I am making a simple shell by using the `fork` and `execvp`. When I run my program and I type in a command like `ls` or `ls -l` it works just how I like it. When that gets done my program is sitting there waiting for another command, but when I put in another valid command or even putting in the same command. `execvp` is saying `ls: cannot access 'ls': no such file or directory`. I don't know why this is happening. I get the same results in running the program again.
Here is my code. I can't copy it through my virtual machine so I took a picture of it.(If someone would like to edit the formating on this that would be awesome. I tried looking at the help)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fq6Xo.jpg

Comment: We need to see some code to be able to help. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Riley Sorry I hit enter while I was putting in tags. I can't get the image to pop up correctly so I had to put an imgur link because my code wouldn't copy through a vm.

Comment: Don't post images of text!

Comment: Don't link to pictures of code. Put the code here or, if it's much too long for clear formatting, use [pastebin](http://pastebin.com)

Comment: Some stupid security settings to prevent "code stealing" by contractors who wrote this code sometimes prevent to copy/paste code from a VM to the real machine where stackoverflow is running. So don't be too hard on him (still, annoying)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: That site-rule exists for good reason, no exceptions. If you cannot copy/paste directly, you can exchange by file or type the code new. That would often help to make a [mcve].

Comment: @Olaf sure! I would be the first to try to workaround those kind of stupid protections. If everyone starts doing this with this excuse, we're done here! It's just the first time I'm witnessing someone coming up with this valid reason. The second one will suffer, promise :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: It is **not** a valid reason. And "If someone would like to edit the formating on this that would be awesome" could be interpreted as giving the finger to site-rules.

Comment: what can I say? you're right, specially about the [mcve] part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code is that you don't reset the argument counter to 0 between command launches.

```
int tokenIndex=0;
do {
```

should be

```
int tokenIndex;
do {
  tokenIndex=0;
```

The first time it works, but the second time you pass `ls` as argument of `ls` hence the message

(try typing `ls ls` in a shell you'll get the exact same message).